# Convert the interface implementation object from one namespace to another since both are having the same interface but different namespace

Tags: c#, design-patterns, architecture

Is there way to convert the interface implementation object from one namespace to another since both are having the same interface but only the namespace is differing?

Use case is like below

```
namespace namespaceA
{
    Public Interface IInterface
    {
        Method1();
        Method2();
    }
}

namespace namespaceB
{
    Public Interface IInterface
    {
        Method1();
        Method2();
    }
}
```

We get two kind of objects.

namespaceA.IInterface object                  - new implementation

namespaceB.IInterface object.                  - exists as a part of legacy implementation.

We wanted to handle only one object in the code i.e. namespaceA.IInterface object, based on the new implementation.
But due to legacy implementation we get namespaceB.IInterface object also.
But we don’t want to any specific handling for legacy object and we wanted to handle in the same way as new object and implementation.

**So if we get an namespaceB.IInterface object, is there way to convert/cast it to namespaceA.IInterface object provided that interface definitions are same but only exists in a different namespace?**

So the code need not worry only about the handling of legacy object.

Comment: From the compiler's perspective, those are two unrelated interfaces, since they are in different namespaces. Not sure if it's possible to just automatically 'convert/cast' one to another.

Comment: Namespaces seems to be an attempt to solve backwards compartibility problem. Confirm?

Comment: Couldn´t you inherit interface B from A? So every legacy-object already **is** an instance of the new interface.

Answer (score 5):

No -  there are two completely different types with no relationship. Just because they have the same member names does not mean that you can cast from one to the other.

You could possibly use an *adapter*, though:

```
public class Adapter: namespaceA.IInterface
{
    private namespaceB.IInterface target;
    public Adapter(namespaceB.IInterface target)
    {
        this.Target = target
    }

    public void Method1() {this.Target.Method1();}
    public void Method2() {this.Target.Method2();}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I´d go with inheriting your new interface from your legacy-one so that every object implementing the legacy-interface also implements the new one and thus can easily be cast to it. This of course assumes the new one has the exact same members. Otherwise you would need to add the implementation for `INew` to all of your classes, which I assume you want to avoid:

```
interface ILegacy : INew { /* completely empty */ }
interface INew 
{ 
    Method1();
    Method2();
}
```

You can even make the `ILegacy`-interface `Obsolete` to be replaced by `INew`.

Comment: Good point! Unless they cannot modify the legacy interface.